# iOS14 Autorotation bug with debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, metalkit, ios14

EDIT: I found the culprit. A single line in code freezes iOS 14 device autorotation in debugger. The XCode project is "dead" forever unless you delete it and create a new copy.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

public static let metalDevice:MTLDevice? = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() //Freezes iOS 14 device

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

}
```

I am seeing an unusual autorotation bug in iOS 14 (beta 3). I have an XCode project with some AVFoundation (AVCaptureSession) & Metal code to setup camera and rendering of camera frames. The code is huge, but here is the strange thing about bug.

- Build the project with XCode 12 and run on iOS 14 device. The view controller doesn't autorotate when connected to debugger. When the app is opened without debugger, autorotation happens,
- Once Autorotation is blocked in debugger, it gets blocked forever for the XCode project. Meaning, if I change the initial view controller to some dummy view controller, it too fails to autorotate!!! Only way is to make a new XCode project to reproduce the issue.
- This does not happen on iOS 13 devices.

Reproducible test case is very difficult to make as there is lot of code. I tried trimming a lot of code but then it is not reproducible. And even to find the culprit code, I will need to make a new XCode project everytime as the project once dead is dead forever!

Is anyone aware of similar issue? Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Creating the MTLDevice as a static was probably always wrong.

Comment: What's the right way?

Comment: I have renderCommandQueue and computeCommandQueue also static.

Comment: A local variable? Usually you just create it and hand it to the context.

Comment: I need it in thousands of places. So made a MetalCamera class and put static func and vars

Comment: Then use a true instance property, not a static. No lazing out on proper object management

Comment: I have a class called MetalCamera in which all such static vars are placed. From there I call MetalCamera.metalDevice, etc. Should I make it singleton?

Comment: Local var doesn't change anything, same behavior

Comment: Probably. But I would also encourage you to file a bug! The mere fact of hooking in the debugger causes a freeze? That’s just wrong.

Comment: Filed it already. But it is severely hindering my project development. I can't test the app in both orientations. And can't go to previous XCode version because there are lot of symbol changes in XCode12 that are incompatible with previous version of XCode.

Comment: I can well believe it. But there's nothing _we_ can do about that. This is not a Stack Overflow matter.

Comment: The weird part is no one faced this bug so far? I have my old XCode project created with XCode 9 or so and the problem doesn't happen there. Only in new projects created with Scene delegates it is an issue.

Comment: Disabling GPU frame capture fixes it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a show stopper and very disabling bug in iOS 14. Either Disabling GPU frame capture or setting GPU frame capture to 'Metal' in the Scheme settings seems to fix it.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks very much, so annoying, I made three different app versions from scratch (programmatically) trying to figure out what was going on, it is also true that once it starts happening that's it. Not sure how you found that solution (I just set my scheme for gpu frame capture, to Metal rather than automatic and that fixed it), thanks again!